# How to make a grayscale without effect overlay text? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to this type of code and wanted to grayscale the background image without effecting the overlay text

HTML CODE

```
<div class="top">   
            <div class="titleMain">
                <div class="titleMainText">
                    <h1>Check out our Store</h1>
                </div>
                <a href="*" class="storeButton">Shop</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.top {
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid;
    background-image: url('../Images/46162.webp');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.titleMain {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 70%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: xx-large;
    filter: none;
}

.titleMainText {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: black;
}
```

I wanted to grayscale the background image without effecting the text infront but can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the filter property to make your background grayscale and use before pseudo before property to apply grayscale without affecting
overlay text.

**Just add filter property to the below class in your CSS:**

```
.top {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 500px;
      padding-top: 50px;
      border-bottom: 10px solid;

 }
.top::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  background-image: url('../Images/46162.webp');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.top {
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid;
    background-image: linear-gradient(black, white),url('https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/sa_pixar_virtualbg_coco_16x9_9ccd7110.jpeg?region=0,0,1920,1080&width=1200');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-blend-mode: saturation;
}

.titleMain {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 70%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: xx-large;
    filter: none;
}

.titleMainText {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
    <div class="top">   
        <div class="titleMain">
            <div class="titleMainText">
                <h1>Check out our Store</h1>
            </div>
            <a href="*" class="storeButton">Shop</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```